# How to resize the box to fix size when using boundingRect?

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

In this project I wanna use contour numbers (cnum) as the index of the objects so I can use them to the next process (I'm working on false human detection using blob tracking). I wanna to resize boundingRect inside DetectMultiScale, how to do that?

and here we go my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::Mat blurred;
    cv::Mat fg;     
    cv::Mat bgmodel;
    cv::Mat threshfg;
    cv::Mat blob;
    int pixblob = 0;
    int tot_bgr = 0;
    int tot_ex_bgr = 0;
    int green0 = 0;
    int green1 = 0;
    int green2 = 0;
    int green3 = 0;

    cv::namedWindow("Frame");   
    cv::namedWindow("Background Model");
    cv::namedWindow("Blob");

    cv::VideoCapture cap("campus.avi"); 

    cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgs;                       
        bgs.nmixtures = 3;
        bgs.history = 500;
        bgs.bShadowDetection = true;                            
        bgs.nShadowDetection = 0;                               
        bgs.fTau = 0.25;                                        

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;               

    cv::CascadeClassifier human;
    assert(human.load("hogcascade_pedestrians.xml"));
    for(;;){
        cap >> frame;   

        cv::GaussianBlur(frame,blurred,cv::Size(3,3),0,0,cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);

        bgs.operator()(blurred,fg);                         
        bgs.getBackgroundImage(bgmodel);                                

        cv::erode(fg,fg,cv::Mat(),cv::Point(-1,-1),1);                         
        cv::dilate(fg,fg,cv::Mat(),cv::Point(-1,-1),3); 

        cv::threshold(fg,threshfg,70.0f,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        cv::findContours(threshfg,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        cv::cvtColor(threshfg,blob,CV_GRAY2RGB);
        cv::drawContours(blob,contours,-1,cv::Scalar(255,255,255),CV_FILLED,8);

        int cmin = 20; 
        int cmax = 1000;
        bool FOD1 = true;
        bool FOD2 = true;
        std::vector<cv::Rect> rects;

        for(int cnum = 0; cnum < contours.size(); cnum++){

            if(contours[cnum].size() > cmin && contours[cnum].size() < cmax){       

                human.detectMultiScale(frame(cv::boundingRect(contours[cnum])),rects); //I wanna resize the box here!

                if(rects.size() > 0){

                        cv::Rect r0 = cv::boundingRect(contours[cnum]);
                        cv::rectangle(frame, 
                                r0, 
                                cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));


                        cv::putText(frame,
                                "HUMAN",
                                cv::Point(r0.x + r0.width / 2, r0.y + r0.height / 2),
                                cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                                0.5,
                                cv::Scalar(0,0,255),
                                2,
                                8);


                }
            }
        }

        cv::imshow("Frame",frame);
        cv::imshow("Background Model",bgmodel);
        cv::imshow("Blob",blob);
        if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'll appreciate any help here. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you debug to see that r0 is correct. Also what does: "error here, I know this is not a cv::Point but I dunno how to handle it" mean? Simply put the position of the text there.

Comment: When I want to add text, I got and error code: Error 1 error C2664: 'cv::putText' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'cv::Point'

Comment: And the code draw nothing, not rectangle at all... :(

Comment: And for the rectangle, the code draw nothing, not rectangle at all... I think the problems here: human.detectMultiScale(frame(cv::boundingRect(contours[cnum])),rects); :(

Comment: I know the problems now, boundingRect crop too small pic. so can't detect the human. thanks! :D